# Create std::pair with unordered_map with custom object

Tags: c++, swap, unordered-map, std-pair

I have a structure

```
    struct modedata {
        unsigned int id;
        float val1;
        float val2;
        std::string mode;
    };
```

I need to create such construction:

```
    std::make_pair(1, std::unordered_map<std::string, modedata >());
```

that is:

```
    std::pair<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<std::string, modedata >> (1, std::unordered_map<std::string, modedata>());
```

I get this error with vscompiller (works fine with mingw):

```
    error C2668: 'swap' : ambiguous call to overloaded function.
```

This makes me confused, as I can use this construction:

```
    std::unordered_map<std::string, modedata>()
```

What is the reasone for this error and how it can be solved?